# Create bpl - Delphi Can't load package the specified module cannot be found

Tags: delphi, pascal, bpl

Recently, I tried install a package .bpl on my computer but it always shows "Delphi Can't load package the specified module cannot be found"

I found the problem was that one of the unit if I export the Function (pre-define) then it will show this problem. If I don't pre-define the function then I can install the package.
However, I need the function from this problematic unit for other unit.

As picture below shown, if I command the red-block area then I can install this package
[image]

However, I will add other Units in the same project, which I will need the function from this D2XXUnit. Can someone help me out?? I totally have no idea why does this happen cause the same package I can install on other computer.

Thanks!!

I've already search some solution, most of them are referring that the directory may be wrong but that's not the case for me.

Comment: I found that one problem I had with that error message was that the package itself required another package that it couldn't find.  Although as it appears that your unit only uses a few standard units, that my not be the problem here.

Comment: A module cannot be found can also mean that a dll is not there. Did you install the D2XX drivers on both computers? As far as I can see the package would use ftd2xx.dll right?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). In RAD Studio, you can right-click in the Messages window and copy the text using the context menu. Code can also be copied and pasted directly into your question. Text is easily readable and searchable, and we do not need to see the rest of the IDE or your desktop.

Comment: Or the .dcp? User programs only need the .bpl, but parts of a package might be linked into the exe ($weakpackage). These parts are in the .dcp, and the compiler surely needs them. Maybe dcu's too.